# Fancybox not running perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the following code in my project

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
        // Options will go here
        infobar: false,
        buttons : [
            "zoom",
            "slideShow",
            //"fullScreen",
            //"download",
            "thumbs",
            "close"
        ],
        wheel : false,
        transitionEffect: "slide",
        // thumbs: false,
     
        // hash            : false,
        
        // keyboard        : true,
        toolbar: true,
        // animationEffect : false,
        // arrows          : true,
        clickContent: false,
        afterLoad: function() {
                   if (!$('.fancybox-button--play').hasClass("fancybox-button--pause")) {
                $('.fancybox-button--play').trigger('click');
            }
            }
        });
```

That code is not executing... however, When I execute it in console it perfectly works... What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to load your script under "$( document ).ready()"